# How to user Material Design icons in the Codename One designer

Tags: material-design, designer, codenameone

I saw the [example](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/material-icons-background-music-geofencing-gradle.html) where it was described how to create with `FontImage` a material design 'like' image; something like:

```
FontImage img = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_THUMB_UP, style);
```

But i am in the CodeName One designer and i am trying to give such icon style to a simple button and i dont the way to do it.
Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

We won't introduce the material design icon font to the old GUI builder as we are in the process of moving to a new rewrite of the GUI builder: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/gui-builder-walkthru.html

Currently we don't have material design icons there either so I've added [an RFE for that](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1676), thanks for the idea.

Notice that you can set the icon by code which is probably not what you are asking. Just use the `beforeShow` callback and set the icon on the component.